# C# .NET Core - Where to store LARGE files for integration testing?

Tags: .net-core, integration-testing, web-api-testing

I'm writing some .NET core API integration tests that verify if a file upload mechanism is working properly.

What is the best practice for storing large files (2Gb +) that I upload for testing purposes? It doesn't seem like a good idea to include these test files in the solution/source control due to their size.

What is the recommended path to take when it comes to writing integration tests using large files?

Comment: Do you need to test that the method accepts a file that large? Or the logic that the method executes with the data read from the file? If it's the second one, I'd try to mock the data read from the file instead of uploading a file with the data.

Comment: It's the first one. It's to verify that we don't get any IIS errors upon uploading a file of a certain size, so I really need to be actually attempting to upload a real file. Also my current approach is to just generate a large dummy file on the disk during test execution, try and upload it, then delete the file on teardown. I don't know if that's the best way but it's what I'm currently doing.

Comment: Can't you simply **generate** a large file using a small piece of code, when needed?

Comment: Yes I can, that's what I mentioned I was currently doing, but wasn't sure if it was the best approach or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options

#1 If contents of the file are not important I would generate stream of size which is xGB on the fly (like serialize array with couple milions of references to the same complex structure). Try to create proper file in console app and save it locally to see if it meets your expectations first.

#2 I would recommend placing these files in Azure Storage. If needed you can generate proper SAS Tokens to make these file available directly through http address or load them as stream using BlobStorage Nuget Package. Blob Storage is also cheap. Or use any server where these files can be placed and be retrievable in your integration tests.

Definitely don't include these files in the project!

Comment: I definitely like the first approach <3

Comment: The first approach is what I ended up going with yesterday and it seems to work pretty well. Thanks for the help everyone.